# I am not able to start new activity in Emulator Android 2.3.3 version, but Android 4.1.2 working fine

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

As I am new to Android development, struggling with a problem. I am testing in Android 4.1.2 its working fine, but when I load it to Android 2.3.3 after that when i click a button, it should start an new activity, but its stops and crashes? what can be problem? the mind_sdk is equals to 9,

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.starter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.starter, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void openS(View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,LoginSU.class );
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void openG(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginGE.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

When person clicks button, it will fire an action openS or openG, after that it will start an new Activity. Its working in Android 4.1.2 but fails in 2.3.3? hwat can be the cause?
Log Cat

```
11-14 10:11:26.817: I/dalvikvm(910): Could not find method kz.bimash.food.security.LoginSU.getActionBar, referenced from method kz.bimash.food.security.LoginSU.onCreate
```

Actually I am not using but its requesting an actionbar.

Comment: Can you post the logcat?

Comment: I have updated the question? what you may suggest? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post your `AndroidManifest.xml` XML and your `res/values/style.xml`? I wonder if the app theme is for a `HOLO` theme which is unsupported on 2.3.3 and below and trying to open the app with `HOLO`. It's a theme which uses the action bar. Or it could be your activity in the manifest is to use a `HOLO` theme.

Instead make a folder in `res/` called `values-v11/` and make a new `style.xml`. You can copy it from the `values/`. Open the copied file up and check the `AppTheme` style. Is the parent  `android:Theme.HOLO` or `android:Theme.HOLO.Light` or something similar? Does it look like this?

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo" />
```

Having separate `values/` and `values-v11/` folders tells the app what theme to do depending on which version is running. Honeycomb 3.0 (v11) and higher would look at the `values-v11` folder for styles and other values, whilst Gingerbread 2.3.4 (v10) and lower would look at the `values/` folder.

Now edit the `values/style.xml` and make the parent `android:Theme.Light` or `android:Theme`

Check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#SelectATheme for more details about how to use multiple themes in the same app.

Answer (score 1):

ActionBar is only support for Android 3 and above versions. 
For older versions of Android to have an ActionBar you can use ActionBarSherlock

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: but i am not using action bar

Comment: When you creating the project set  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" /> in the AndroidManifest.xml